# Repair GNU GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as **Dual-Boot with Windows 7** and everything worked superb. Then as I booted my PC **GNU Grub rescue** popped up and told me, that it couldn't find my **SSD**.

But as I booted into the **Boot selecter** of the **BIOS** it worked great and both OS's would boot without porblems. But it annoys me, that I have to boot into the Boot Selector everytime and I don't want to delete Ubuntu.

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from boot-repair and fix grub from there (using the recommended repair). Here's the [community wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).